# Obtaining of all values of checkboxes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, checkbox

I have a html-form with checkboxes.
It is required that has been checked by at least one any checkbox.
How do I use JavaScript to get the values ​​of all checkboxes, and if there is not one checked among checkboxes then show alert with message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have tagged this post with `jquery` here is a jQuery option.

This function selects all the checkboxes on the page, narrows it down to only the checked ones, then get's the size of the jQuery object.

```
if ($('input:checkbox').prop('checked').size() == 0)
{
alert('no checkboxes were checked');
}
```

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// utility function
function toArray(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = obj[i];
  }
  return arr;
}

// get the form
var someForm = ...;
// get all elements and check whether any has type "checkbox" and is checked.
var checked = toArray(someForm.elements).some(function (el) {
  return el.type === "checkbox" && el.checked;
});

if (!checked) {
  alert("please check a box");
}
```

For browser support use the [DOM-shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim) and the [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)